# BERT word embbeding on a simple dataset

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I want to learn how can I use BERt for word embbeding. I tried this code:

```
from bert_serving.client import BertClient
bc = BertClient()
```

But the problem is that it took a lot and I finally couldn't run it even after 10 hours. I've read that it's a GPU intensive task. I use my own laptop with 8GB GPU.
my question is, there is a way that I can use BERT for a small dataset on my own laptop?